# Add hashes with duplicate keys to array

Tags: powershell, dictionary, array

I have a bunch of hashes in powershell with identical keys.  Though creating an array of hashes with different keys is straightforward and thoroughly discussed on the internet, I'm unable to find any information about adding hashes to an array with duplicate keys.

Two errors I have received when attempting this:

`Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'time'  Key being added: 'time'`

`A hash table can only be added to another hash table.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add duplicate keys to hashtables, because hashtables by design can only contain unique keys. If you need to store duplicate key/value pairs, use arrays.

> I'm using an array of independent hash tables, but somehow when you add the hashtable to the array, the keys need to be unique across all the hashtables in the array

That' strange, because it should work fine. Example:

```powershell
$ArrayOfHashtables = @{Aplha = 'Bravo'}, @{Charlie = 'Delta'}, @{Echo = 'Foxtrot'}
$ArrayOfHashtables +  @{Charlie = 'Delta'}
```

Result:

```powershell
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Aplha                          Bravo
Charlie                        Delta
Echo                           Foxtrot
Charlie                        Delta
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm using an array of independent hash tables, but somehow when you add the hashtable to the array, the keys need to be unique across all the hashtables in the array

Comment: @twinlakes It should work fine, see update. Can we see your code?

Comment: Weird.  I'm guessing then it could've been a bug caused by automatically unwrapping length = 1 arrays.  Unfortunately, I don't have the original code as my situation allowed me to use `System.Collections.Queue` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was having trouble passing information to a REST API that required multiple attributes using the duplicate keys.